# Flipview inside a gridview inside a semantizoom

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, gridview, flipview

i have a flipview inside a gridview inside a semanticzoom. the gridview is there because i can't direclty nest the flipview inside the semanticzoom. inside the flipview i show images fullscreen. the user taps a image, the image descriptions visibility toggles from visible to colappsed. when i left click with a mouse on the image it get's "selected" (it gets pushed to the background a little), and just stays selected until i right click with the mouse (it gets pushed back to the forground). i have disabled selecting on the gridview, and flipview does not have the ability to select items (i think). I want the select behaviour to stop but i don't know what is causing it.
This is just an incomplete sample, not the full complete code

```
<SemanticZoom Name="ModalGallerySemanticZoom" Padding="0" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed" ViewChangeStarted="ModalGallerySemanticZoom_ViewChangeStarted"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView Name="ZoomedInGridView" IsItemClickEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" SelectionMode="None" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False" CanReorderItems="False" CanDragItems="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle >
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Grid Margin="-5,-5,0,-10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <FlipView Tapped="ModalGalleryFlipView_Tapped" Padding="0" SelectionChanged="ModalGalleryFlipView_SelectionChanged" Margin="0" Name="ModalGalleryFlipView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GalleryMainTemplate}" /><Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Name="ModalGalleryBackButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0" Click="ModalGalleryBackButton_Click" Padding="10,15,10,10" > <Image Stretch="None"  Source="/Assets/Left-Arrow.png"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```

i have tried again in a more clearer example

```
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView Name="ZoomedInGridView" IsItemClickEnabled="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" SelectionMode="None" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False" CanReorderItems="False" CanDragItems="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="0" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle >
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <FlipView>
                <Image Height="1000" Width="1000" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="/Assets/Twitter.png"/>
                <Image Height="1000" Width="1000" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="/Assets/Facebook.png"/>
                </FlipView>
            </GridView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```

The results are the same, i can select the two images when i should have not. Actually it seams the whole flipview gets selected. How do i stop the flipview from being selected?

Comment: I have found the answer, but i can't post it as a answer yet. the solution was to use a costum style for gridviewitem like shown here: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/07/09/The-taming-of-the-Metro-GridView.aspx now my flipview does not enter the "pressed" state when it gets tapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a costum style for gridviewitem like shown here: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/07/09/The-taming-of-the-Metro-GridView.aspx now my flipview does not enter the "pressed" state when it gets tapped